# Xcode. How do I customize the console logging output

Tags: xcode4

In Xcode when I NSLog things I get a lot of extra crud in the console output I would rather not have. Here is a typical example:

`2012-06-07 10:07:26.046 IGV[13066:707] -[RootScrollView layoutSubviews] [Line 79] ratios - right 0.997 chrEnd 1.233. ThresholdLeft`

How do I eliminate the `2012-06-07 10:07:26.046 IGV[13066:707]`?

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1):

You can use printf() instead of NSLog to get control over the entire string that is printed to the console.

e.g.

```
float right = 0.997;
float chrEnd = 1.233;

printf("ratios - right %f chrEnd %f.", right, chrEnd);
```

Will give you something similar to what you want.